# Netcoreapp2.0 won't start in Azure App Service with Error 500 and no logs

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-2.0

All of a sudden my  Azure App Service can't start a aspnetcore2.0 and there is no logs. Just error 500 and no logs in Application Insights or Streaming Servicecs in Kudu.

App works perfectly on localhost, but standalone and with IIS Express and was working fine before in Azure yesterday.

How can I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR;  Azure is probably having issues with binding redirects due to other runtimes and .NET versions. Add this to your csproj in the calling code (usually your web project).

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**Troubleshooting steps:**

1. Enable startup logging

   ```
   public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) => WebHost
       .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
       .CaptureStartupErrors(true)
       [...]
   ```
2. Open Kudu tools and watch the streaming log service

   https://.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/logstream

where you might find an error like:

```
2017-12-09 11:53:33.304 +00:00 [Error] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel: Connection id "0HL9UVDQACN2F", Request id "0HL9UVDQACN2F:00000002": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.WebRequest, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Net.Http.WebRequest, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at Microsoft.Rest.ServiceClient`1.CreateRootHandler()
```

[..]

Look for places where your code might load an assembly, I found out that:

```
File name: 'System.Net.Http.WebRequest, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at Microsoft.Rest.ServiceClient`1.CreateRootHandler()
   at MyApp.MiddleLayer.Services.AzureSearch.DependencyInjection.<>c.<AddAzureSearch>b__0_1(IServiceProvider x) in C:\<Path>.Services.AzureSearch\DependencyInjection.cs:line 27
```

Which is where I add my Azure Search code in my app.

3. Either add missing assemblies, or as in my case where Azure Search SDK was referencing old assembly, enable `AutoGenerateBindingRedirects` as described in top of this post.

Comment: So it suddenly broke without you making any new deployment? Are you using ASP.NET Core on .NET Core or on Full Framework? Could you share your web app name, either directly or [indirectly](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly)? Also, can you check if it was updated to 2016, in case that's related?

Comment: No it broke after making a deployment but worked before. Using .NET Core 2.0. Azure Search SDK broke it.

Comment: the build process on Azure should be the same as in VS, I am guessing that `System.Net.Http.WebRequest` was loaded from [nuget cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-nuget-cache) when you were testing locally, can you try 1. publish to [local folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/publishing-with-visual-studio) and see if the missing assembly was presented? or 2. clear the cache and run it again?

Comment: I cleared cache so It couldn't be that. Seems like version mismatched on my local machine and deployed version on Azure.